# How to tie fragment destination to menu items in bottom nav bar?

Tags: android

I want to use the navigation and destination system in android so when a menu item in the bottom nav bar is clicked it goes to a fragment.

I created 3 empty fragments and followed this guide to tie the items to the fragments but when I click the menu items, nothing happens.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

I made sure that the item id from the menu has the same id as the fragment too.
how can I make this work?

Here is my Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    bottom_navigation
        .setupWithNavController(navController)
  }  
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

}
```

This is the activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

And this is the bottom nav bar menu:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24px"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24px"
    android:title="Search" />    
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_face_24px"
    android:title="Profile" />
```

Navigation.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.puntogris.herewego.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_profileFragment"
        app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:name="com.puntogris.herewego.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_searchFragment"
        app:destination="@id/searchFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
    android:name="com.puntogris.herewego.search.SearchFragment"
    android:label="fragment_search"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
```

Comment: Can you include your navigation XML?

Comment: sure thing, here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `android:id`s do not match.

Your menu XML uses `android:id="@+id/fragment_home"`, but your navigation XML uses `android:id="@+id/homeFragment"`.

These need to be the same name. For example, you could change your menu XML to be

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24px"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24px"
        android:title="Search" />    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_face_24px"
        android:title="Profile" />
</menu>
```